# basic Dynamic Select list PHP & AJAX Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I was trying to get a dynamic dependent select list using AJAX, but unable to get the second list. Here is my code. gethint.php is working fine. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>      

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#brand').change(function()
            {
                var cid=$('#brand').val();
                if(cid !=0)
                {

                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url: 'gethint.php',
                    data: {id:cid},
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(returndata)
                        {
                            $('#model').html(returndata);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Car Comparision </h1>
        </header>
        <form method="post" action="">
            Brand 1:
            <select id="brand" class="brand">
                    <?php
                    include "connect.php"; 
                    $query=$con->query("SELECT * FROM car");
                    while($brand=$query->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                    $brand_sel='<option value="'.$brand['id'].'"'.">".$brand['brand'].'</option>'."\n";
                    echo $brand_sel;
                    }
                    ?>
            </select>
            Model 1:
            <select id="model" class="model">
            <option value="0">Please select a city</option>
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

code for my gethint.php file

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
$Query='SELECT * FROM model WHERE id='.$_POST['id'];
$sql=$con->query($Query) or die(mysql_error());
//print_r($Query);
while($row=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row['model_name'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error recognized? Please confirm, the ajax response is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('#brand').on('change', function() {
            var cid=$('#brand').val();
            if(cid !=0)
            {

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: 'gethint.php',
                data: {id:cid},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata)
                    {
                        $('#model').html(returndata);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank U. But why didn't my old code worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it of a different a way:

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
$Query='SELECT * FROM model WHERE id='.$_POST['id'];
$sql=$con->query($Query) or die(mysql_error());
//print_r($Query);

$elements = [];
while($row=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $item = ["id" => $row['id'], "model_name" => $row['model_name']]
    array_push($elements , $item)

}
echo $elements;

?>
```

I would send a associative array which contains all the items of your select. I would also modify your script to:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#brand').change(function()
        {
            var cid=$('#brand').val();
            if(cid !=0)
            {

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: 'gethint.php',
                data: {id:cid},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata)
                    {
                        returndata.each(data,function(){
                            $('#model').append("<option value="+data.id+">"+data.model_name+"</option>")
                         })

                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I worried about really you are passing the right value to the ajax.

See the data render for first `select` is:

```
$brand_sel='<option value="'.$brand['id'].'"'.">".$brand['brand'].'</option>'."\n";
```

It should be like this:

`$brand_sel='<option value="'.$brand['id'].'">'.$brand['brand'].'</option>\n';`

As per my above comment please let us know if any error showing related to jQuery or PHP.

Also, check the passing data to ajax is in correct format.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this me. I was fed up with not working code so done too much editing resulted messing up all thing. BTW Abhishek's solution is working fine for me.